# Code migration from Swift 2.x to Swift 4 (for loop)

Tags: swift, for-loop, migration

I got this code snippet from the web, but my Xcode is complaining:

> C-style for statement has been removed in Swift 3

Can someone help me migrate the following code to Swift 4?

```
for (var i = 1; i < dataByLine.count; i++) {

}
```

Comment: try `for i in 1..< dataByLine.count {

}`

Comment: More than 50 SO search results for `[swift] C style for statement` and none of them helped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your statement in Swift 4:

```
for i in 1..<dataByLine.count {

}
```